# How to read textbox1 within quotes?

Tags: c#

I know the title is worded badly, but I didn't really know how to explain it. I'm trying to read a textbox's value and use it. Here's an example below.

```
Jtag.Call(0x82254940, -1, 0, "c \"textBox1.Text\"");
```

That wouldn't work because it's between some quotes, I've also tried +textBox1+ but to no avail, so I'd like some help getting it to work please.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly doesnt work for you , setting value or getting value from text box ?

Comment: what kind of parameter does Jtag.Call method expect?

Comment: What is `Jtag.Call` method ?

Comment: `Jtag.Call(0x82254940, -1, 0, "c \"+textBox1.Text+\"");`

Comment: When it displays the text it just says textBox1.Text and not the actual contents of the textbox.

Comment: Why you are putting textbox1.Text call in quotes ? shouldn't it be `"c \"" + textBox1.Text + "\""`

Comment: Jtag.Call is a dll to set and get memory of an Xbox 360.

Comment: Jtag.Call(0x82254940, -1, 0, textBox1.Text);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to do string interpolation (insert the value of a variable into a string), in C#, you can use either `string.Format` (usually the preferred way):

```
string command = string.Format("c \"{0}\"", textBox1.Text);
Jtag.Call(0x82254940, -1, 0, command);
```

or string concatenation (using `+`):

```
string command = "c \"" + textBox1.Text + "\"";
Jtag.Call(0x82254940, -1, 0, command);
```

I think the confusing part in your example is that you have the need to quote the value, using `\"`. This escapes the quote symbol and makes a literal `"` appear in the string; it does not mark the end of one part of the string. You need to close the string:

```
string first = "string ending with a quote, here \"";
string second = "\" this one starts with a quote.";
```

If you've got syntax colouring enabled in Visual Studio, it should be fairly obvious what's a string and what's not.

Answer (score 0):

```
Jtag.Call(0x82254940, -1, 0, "c \"" + textBox1.Text + "\"");
```

But for clarity, I'd go with Rogers suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Jtag.Call(0x82254940, -1, 0, "c \"" + textBox1.Text + "\"");
```

or use `String.Format`:

```
Jtag.Call(0x82254940, -1, 0, String.Format("c \"{0}\"", textBox1.Text ));
```